# How do I find and remove row chunks that all have missing data in an R data.frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, geo

I am using a data frame that includes `Pixel ID`, `Year`, XY coordinates, and `Temperature` values. For some Pixel IDs, the `Temperature` value is `NA` for each year (see `Pixel ID` 1). For other pixel IDs, the `Temperature` value is 'NA' for only some years (see `Pixel ID` 2). What I would like is to find and remove those `Pixel ID` if all of the values for all of the years (`Year` always repeats from 2001-2005) are `NA`. I would like to keep those `Pixel ID` if even one of the values is a non-`NA` value.

Here is an example of the data frame I am working with

```
> head(Temperature_sorted, n = 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   PixelID  Year     X     Y Temperature
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1       1  2001  70.8  73.5          NA
 2       1  2002  70.8  73.5          NA
 3       1  2003  70.8  73.5          NA
 4       1  2004  70.8  73.5          NA
 5       1  2005  70.8  73.5          NA
 6       2  2001  70.8  73.5         0.2
 7       2  2002  70.8  73.5         0.4
 8       2  2003  70.8  73.5          NA
 9       2  2004  70.8  73.5         0.5
10       2  2005  70.8  73.5         0.3
```

and here is an example of the output I would like

```
> head(Temperature_sorted, n = 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   PixelID  Year     X     Y Temperature
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1       2  2001  70.8  73.5         0.2
 2       2  2002  70.8  73.5         0.4
 3       2  2003  70.8  73.5          NA
 4       2  2004  70.8  73.5         0.5
 5       2  2005  70.8  73.5         0.3
 6       3  2001  70.8  73.5          NA
 7       3  2002  70.8  73.5         0.7
 8       3  2003  70.8  73.5         0.9
 9       3  2004  70.8  73.5          NA
10       3  2005  70.8  73.5         0.9
```

I have several thousand `Pixel ID` values so I would like to use a for loop if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

Temperature_sorted %>%
  group_by(PixelID) %>%
  filter(any(!is.na(Temperature)))
```

First we group rows by PixelID, then for each row, we check if any rows with the same PixelID have a Temperature value that is not NA.

Answer (score 1):

We can select those groups which do not have all `NA`'s.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, !ave(is.na(Temperature), PixelID, FUN = all)) 

#   PixelID Year    X    Y Temperature
#6        2 2001 70.8 73.5         0.2
#7        2 2002 70.8 73.5         0.4
#8        2 2003 70.8 73.5          NA
#9        2 2004 70.8 73.5         0.5
#10       2 2005 70.8 73.5         0.3
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(PixelID) %>%  filter(!all(is.na(Temperature)))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[!all(is.na(Temperature))], PixelID]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(PixelID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Year = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L), X = c(70.8, 70.8, 70.8, 70.8, 70.8, 70.8, 
70.8, 70.8, 70.8, 70.8), Y = c(73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 
73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5), Temperature = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.2, 0.4, NA, 0.5, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: A _tour de force_! Answers in `Base R`, `dplyr` and `data.table`.  I'm impressed.